# Javascript BigInt.js How to Divide big numbers

Tags: javascript, bigint

http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.js

I am using the leemon bigint.js library, but I am having trouble figuring out how to divide one big number by another.  Here is what I have so far:

```
var a = str2bigInt("100",10);
var b = int2bigInt("5", 10);
var result = [];
var r = [];
divide_(a,b,result,r)
alert(bigInt2str(result,10));
```

but when I alert(result) the output is 0.  The result should be 20?  Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this `BigInt.js` library expects the result arrays to already have sufficient length to store the result; using empty arrays doesn't work.

This code however works as expected:

```
var a = str2bigInt("100",10);
var b = int2bigInt("5", 10);
var result = new Array(2);
var r = new Array(2);
divide_(a,b,result,r);
alert(bigInt2str(result,10));
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the line

```
var b = int2bigInt("5", 10);
```

should be

```
var b = str2bigInt("5", 10);
```

The function `int2bigInt` expects an integer, not a string.

Comment: Could you explain what is the second parameter? I have to port this function to other language, so confused