# Using BigInt numbers in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, biginteger, bigint

I want to draw a highStock chart in javascrtipt using highcharts plugin and I want to show very large numbers (in range of BigInt) in it. my problem is that i don't want to show them with scientific notation, I want real numbers in my chart but when I convert numbers to real numbers they become strings and highchart can't show them.

Edit :

For example :

I have this chart with this specific data :

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {                                                            
                    {
                        name : 'بازار',
                        data : [[1180396800000 , 123456789123456789123456789],[1180483200000 , 987654321987654321987654321],...],                        
                    }
                ]
});
```

And it shows the data like picture below with scientific notation, I want to show data in the chart as I inserted for example like this "987654321987654321987654321"!

[image]

Comment: Have you an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case is not related with highcharts, because it is default problem in javascirpt. See the example:

```
alert(123456789123456789123456789);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lawg4/

In the alert, you will notice that javascript return with epsilon.

Related topic: [Javascript BigInt.js How to Divide big numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959255/javascript-bigint-js-how-to-divide-big-numbers)